# Pushing calculate sum to input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to push calculate sum those after **Line total:** display in input not in text.

I try add some input for example:

```
<input id="totalline" name="totalline" value="" />
```

and change this:

```
var calculate = function(el) {
var percent = el.find('input[name="percent[]"]').val();
var additional = el.find('input[name="additional[]"]').val();
var total = el.find('span.total');
var totalValue = ($("#weight").val() * percent / (100 - additional)).toFixed(2);
total.text(totalValue);
}
```

to this:

```
var calculate = function(el) {
var percent = el.find('input[name="percent[]"]').val();
var additional = el.find('input[name="additional[]"]').val();
var total = el.find('span.total');
var totalValue = ($("#weight").val() * percent / (100 - additional)).toFixed(2);
$('#totalline').val(totalValue); //<-this line changed
}
```

But this is not work like I want to.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0ddbzu7/).

Comment: Can you be more specific, what does not works _like you want to_ ? Because your code seams to be Ok, maybe the probleme isn't where you set the value but where you calculate it.

Comment: When I fill fields in first fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v0ddbzu7 and click + button everything works good, but in second it is not http://jsfiddle.net/v0ddbzu7/1/

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/v0ddbzu7/2/ working example

Comment: @Deep3015 Using such specific selectors like that is typically a bad idea. It makes maintaining/updating your UI a nightmare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use an ID selector when there will be multiple elements with the same ID on the page (when you press the `+` button to add a new row). Simply change your selector to `var total = el.find("[name='totalline']");` to ensure that you are always grabbing the correct input.

This is what it should look like:

#### HTML

```
Line total: <input name="totalline" value="" />
```

#### JS

```
var calculate = function(el) {
  var percent = el.find('input[name="percent[]"]').val();
  var additional = el.find('input[name="additional[]"]').val();
  var total = el.find("[name='totalline']");
  var totalValue = ($("#weight").val() * percent / (100 - additional)).toFixed(2);
  total.val(totalValue);
}
```